# Issue with executing spark jobs

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, hadoop-yarn

In our big data project, Spark yarn cluster we have 3 nodes.

[image]

created 5 executors + 1 driver

[image]

When I go through the spark UI, I can see most of the task time was done by executor 4. I don't know why.

[image]

When I go through the logs, it seems okay. I want the proper utilization of resources and concurrent execution. Please help me with it.

Note: I was able to access one node http://node01:8042, but not able to access the remaining nodes. When I try to access I am getting error.
"Sorry, got error 500: Please consult RFC 2616 for meanings of the error code."
If possible, please explain this also.

Thanks.